# How can I auto select the Configurable product dropdown option if only one option is available?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

Can anyone let me know that in the configurable product dropdown attribute have only one option available so it should be auto select ?

[image]

In the screenshot you can see that only A is available so after selection of other attribute it should auto select.

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento2-Default-dropdown-value/td-p/96053

Comment: this is not the solution, I have to auto select if have only one option available. The above link is by default first option will be selected.

Comment: if you have only one option then why are you making configurable product ?just a curiosity

Comment: there is 4 to 5 attribute, and after selection of other attribute this need to be auto select.
I think you are not getting my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try replacing

```
if (i == 0) {this.options.values[attributeId] = options[i].id;}
```

with

```
if (options.length == 1 ) {this.options.values[attributeId] = options[i].id;}
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themenamme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js

just before the end of for loop as [explained](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento2-Default-dropdown-value/td-p/96053) in this example.

Note: In my case, configurable products are only with selectable dropdown and with these as options

Colors and Sizes, few of the colors have only one option like black. So, the above code works well by pre-selecting if the Colors options have only one option.